# OTA update on Raspberry PI?

Tags: remote, update, bootloader, rpi-update

I want to do OTA (Over The Air) updates in my Raspberry Pi. I have seen a lot of services on the internet like mender.io, but they are all quite expensive. Is there any easy/less expensive way to do OTA updates in my RPI? For example, I have 2 partitons in my RPI. In one partition my current OS is running, and now I download the updated OS and would like to install it on 2nd partition. If the installation gets completed without any problem then the bootloader will boot from this partition next time.

Can somebody guide me how can this be achievable?

Comment: This would be a feature of the operating system itself.  Since most or all of the linux distros commonly used on the Pi have it intrinsically (eg. on Raspbian `apt update; apt upgrade`), it's not clear what you are looking for...

Comment: do you know what does OTA means? whoever would know the answer knows really well what i am asking here. I dont get it why people close the post without even asking..

Comment: I was asking; the question can be re-opened.  If there's a reason for closing a question, it is closed.  It's then up to the OP to fix what is wrong, and not the other way around. Ie., You are not asked to "fix this *or* I will close the question".  So: You need to provide a definition of **over the air update** which excludes normal package managers (eg., if you want to update software that is not provided by the distro -- but note this is likely off-topic here as the brand of hardware is unlikely to be relevant).  You can use as many online references as you like.

Comment: In my experience, OTA updates are used in cases where you have a single piece of code running on a device, ie the firmware on a microcontroller, where you need to be able to download the update, check that its valid (crc or whatever) and then boot that firmware the next time.  With a full linux system there is already checks in place when downloading/updating new packages, and they can be rolled back if there is an issue after updating. Not really sure why you would want to download an entire partition image every time you want to update a little piece of code, update the part needed.

Comment: @goldilocksm, i asked the same question on superuser and there my question was closed because according to them it exactly fit in this forum thats why i have posted it here. I am looking for the over the air update for my raspberrypi e.g. if i have a code running and i did some changes which e.g. incudes some python packages and some apt-get packages. how can i update this to 100s of devices? if e.g. i send a http request to a shell script triggering apt-get update and it fails then what i am gonna do to solve this problem?

Comment: @ChadG thanks for your reply. The reason behind thinking of getting the whole os update is that e.g. what i gonna do if e.g. apt-get updates fails or e.g. i need some pip package or npm package and it get fails to install. i dont want to ssh the devices individually to check the logs and interact it. i were also not sure about sending the security updates over http. I hope i have explained it correctly. if you dont understand anything please feel free to ask or correct me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479), but someone may come by and help you sort through it.

Comment: You can have a script that updates apt or rpm packages. You can also distribute  a script that can install new packages, pull new code/binary's from your own repo ect. There is no need to try and pull Gigabytes worth of data containing the OS and all the software when your not updating all the software....

Comment: Again, the idea of OTA updates that store a full copy of a firmware in a partition and then boot from that is for cases where the device only runs one piece of code (microcontroller). For two reasons. 1) it cant update its code while running. 2) it needs to be able to fall back in the event of an incomplete download or corrupt data. Again this is all handled by apt-get and other package managers so just go ahead and automate them.

Comment: The one peice of code that cannot really be updated in real time is the kernel, but again the OS already has ways of dealing with this. It stores old versions of the kernel that can be loaded on reboot if there is a problem. Again this can all be handled via automated scripts, there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @chad..thanks for the explanation.. How can i add some kind of a watchdog to take a look at the process if its done successfully? for both apllication and apt-get packages?and is Old system automatically rollback to older version or do we have to trigger somthing in a shell script?

Comment: That's part of what the package manager does.  It's certainly not perfect, but you don't really think it is just plain dumb do you?  That stuff has been around for *20 years* and is used in probably *the broadest context that **any** software* could be, meaning, `apt` has been deployed everywhere for a long time.  You should try to learn about that first, before you assume it doesn't cover most of what you want.  After that, you should investigate automated configuration managers such as *chef* or *puppet*, and conventional, efficient methods of incremental backup such as *rsync*...

Comment: Hawkbit + rauc (or) swupdate might be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hawkbit](https://eclipse.dev/hawkbit/) as a deploy server.

And [rauc](https://rauc.io/) (or) [swupdate](https://github.com/sbabic/swupdate) as a client on RaspberryPi side.

(*I've converted @Fl0v0 [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108023/ota-update-on-raspberry-pi?newreg=49e7ff54fc1b4ccbba0bf998fd5c8236#comment184156_108023) to answer and added links*)